# conversion failed when converting datetime from character string in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

I have one project use asp.net mvc 5 and the database use SQL Server 2008, when I deploy the application in IIS server A use windows 7 its normal and work, but when I deploy in IIS server B use windows server 2008 sp 1, the application not work. when I input values the error is

```
    Server Error in '/SystemPurchase' Application.

Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +388
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +688
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4403
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +82
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +135
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6665229
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +6667096
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +577
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +107
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +288
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +302
   SystemPurchase.Models.transaction.insert() in c:\Users\Administrator.USer-PC.000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SystemPurchase\SystemPurchase\Models\transaction.cs:196
   SystemPurchase.Controllers.NewEntryController.Index(HttpPostedFileBase filequo1, HttpPostedFileBase filetool1, HttpPostedFileBase filequo2, HttpPostedFileBase filetool2, HttpPostedFileBase filequo3, HttpPostedFileBase filetool3, HttpPostedFileBase filequo4, HttpPostedFileBase filetool4, HttpPostedFileBase filepo, HttpPostedFileBase filetool, FormCollection abc, transaction aa) in c:\Users\Administrator.USer-PC.000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SystemPurchase\SystemPurchase\Controllers\NewEntryController.cs:199
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +835
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +217
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +112
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +231
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

I input a date from a model use

```
Datetime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss tt")
```

in server A its work and no error, but in server B its error

any ideas to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a specific `FormatProvider`, like below:

```
Datetime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("you culture Info"));
```

[Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/) is a useful link, in which you will fund a list of all the available culture names.

Comment: thx for reply @chirstos, I use it and still not work in server B, any other suggestion ?

Comment: you welcome dude. Let me see your updated post and I hope I will come back with a solution.

Comment: Please try this one: Go to your database and change the type of your column from `DATETIME` TO `DATETIME2` and please let me know if this works. Thanks

Comment: thx dude but datetime2 type data not valid in sql server 2008

Comment: Could you please psot the code you use for the insertion of new data to your table. Thank you in advance. (Please include this to your original post, not as a comment :) )

Answer (score -1):

You may use the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)

And choose the format that you need

For example :

```
DateTime OutputDate = null;
 DateTime.TryParseExact(Datetime.Now.ToString(), "yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out OutputDate);
```

Comment: use debugging, What is the `OutputDate` 's value